# Firebase Database replace user id Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a project with Firebase and cloud functions but I'm struggling here :

I have a user with a related id. 
That id (let's call it 'oldID') is used in other nodes of the database. 
For some reasons I need to change that id and replace it with another one.

I want to use a cloud function in order to do it because I know that this 'replace all' feature is not supported by Firebase. By the way, I cannot find a way to cycle over all the possible nodes and look for that specific oldID.

Do you guys have any suggestion ?

Thanks, 
PR

**EXAMPLE**

users --

```
  id1 --
      //user1 data
  id2 --
      //user2 data
```

groups --

```
  group1 --
      id1:email1
      id2:email2
  group2--
```

Then, at some point, I need to change the id of the user 1 (id1) into another id (let's say newid1). What I need is this example to change in :

users --

```
  newid1 --
      //user1 data
  id2 --
      //user2 data
```

groups --

```
  group1 --
      newid1:email1
      id2:email2
  group2--
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole users collection <strike>`.where('oldID', '==', <YOUR-VALUE>)`</strike> iterate through every document <strike>and add the edited value to a batch</strike> delete it, and create a new one with its copy, you need to make a deep copy with Object.assign() or better the spread operator:

```
let batch = firestore.batch()

firebase.firestore().collection('users').get().then(snap => {
   snap.forEach(doc => {
     let newID = // I don't know where you're getting this, your <<oldID>> is doc.id

     let userData = { ... doc.data() }

     batch.delete(doc.ref)
     batch.set(firestore.collection('users').doc(newID), userData)
   })

   return batch.commit()
 }).then(outcome => {
    console.log(outcome)
    res.end()
 }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e)
 })
```

Comment: Hi Davide, got your point but I think I maybe bad explained my question. 
The user id is actually the id that i want to change, I cannot do that 'where' function because I do not know about the value, I want to replace the key

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time-edit you need to do. I would recommend exporting you entire database:

`On the top right click 'Export JSON'`

Once you have downloaded the database, just open it in an editor and perform a find/replace of the old/new uids then:

`On the top right click 'Import JSON'`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but I'm looking for a way to do it programmatically because unfortunately it's not a one-time-edit, but I would need it several times.